# Creation of concurrency objects dramatically slows down execution time

Tags: c, go, concurrency

I have gotten this code and been asked to find out how I can use concurrency to speed up the process.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define SIZE 10000000

volatile float a[SIZE];
volatile float b[SIZE];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  long int       i;
  double         sum;
  struct timeval time1, time2;

  srand(time(0));

  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    a[i] = rand();
    b[i] = rand();
  }

  gettimeofday(&time1, 0); //Original place

  sum = 0.0;
  
  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    sum = sum + a[i]*b[i];
  }

  gettimeofday(&time2, 0);
  
  printf("Elapsed time (us) = %d\n", (time2.tv_sec-time1.tv_sec)*1000000 + time2.tv_usec - time1.tv_usec);

  return 0;
}
```

if I run the code I get the output

```
Elapsed time (us) = 26546
```

Then I wrote a similar program in Go

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

const size int64 = 10000000

var (
    a = [size]float32{}
    b = [size]float32{}
)

func main() {
    var (
        i     int64
        sum   float32
        time1 time.Time
        time2 time.Time
    )

    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

    for i = 0; i < size; i++ {
        a[i] = rand.Float32()
        b[i] = rand.Float32()
    }

    time1 = time.Now() //Original place

    sum = 0.0

    for i = 0; i < size; i++ {
        sum = sum + a[i] + b[i]
    }

    time2 = time.Now()

    fmt.Printf("Elapsed time (us) = %d\n", time2.Sub(time1).Microseconds())
}
```

An I get this output (which was very surprisingly faster than the C version)

```
Elapsed time (us) = 2462
```

My job was to try to make it faster with concurrency, and I was thinking that the creation of the arrays could be speed up if they would be run in parallel, However the timer is only started after the creation. So then I don't really know how I can speed it up since the values need to be merges which would be a sequential process.

So I move the start timer over the creation time and get for the c program:

```
Elapsed time (us) = 172496
```

and for the go program:

```
Elapsed time (us) = 247603
```

So now go is slower than C as expected.

Then I tried to change my go program to create each array in its own goroutine:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

const size int = 10000000

var (
    a = [size]float64{}
    b = [size]float64{}
)

func main() {
    var (
        wg    sync.WaitGroup
        sum   float64
        time1 time.Time
        time2 time.Time
    )

    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

    wg.Add(2)

    time1 = time.Now()

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
            a[i] = rand.Float64()
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
            b[i] = rand.Float64()
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    wg.Wait()

    sum = 0.0

    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        sum = sum + a[i] + b[i]
    }

    time2 = time.Now()

    fmt.Printf("Elapsed time (us) = %d\n", time2.Sub(time1).Microseconds())
}
```

and I get the output:

```
Elapsed time (us) = 395808
```

Which is quite slow. and I expect that this has something to do with the invokation of the functions and the waitgroup logic.

Then I tried with channels.

Which just made the program take forever, and the code waay to long.

Then I tried with each coroutine adding the fields itself

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

const size int = 10000000

func main() {
    var (
        wg    sync.WaitGroup
        sum   float64
        asum  float64
        bsum  float64
        time1 time.Time
        time2 time.Time
    )

    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

    wg.Add(2)

    time1 = time.Now()

    go func() {
        asum = 0
        for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
            asum = asum + rand.Float64()
        }

        wg.Done()
    }()

    go func() {
        bsum = 0
        for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
            bsum = bsum + rand.Float64()
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    wg.Wait()

    sum = asum + bsum

    time2 = time.Now()

    fmt.Printf("Elapsed time (us) = %d\n", time2.Sub(time1).Microseconds())
    fmt.Println(sum)
}
```

which returned

```
Elapsed time (us) = 395182
1.000137482475232e+07
```

I had to use the sum as well to be able to run the program - thats why I print it.

---

So I just cant seem to get this program to run any faster with concurrency.

Does anyone have a hint for me? or should I just run more jobs before concurrency will have any effect? Is it just because I only deal with 2 jobs in this case, and because arrays are so fast to process?

Comment: In your C code, your are multiplying `a[i]` with `b[i]`, whereas in your Go code, you are adding `a[i]` with `b[i]`. This does not seem like a fair comparison.

Comment: Using `volatile` may prevent certain compiler optimizations. If you want to ensure that your calculations have an observable effect, so that the calculations cannot be optimized away by the compiler, then you may want to simply print `sum` instead.

Comment: When benchmarking programs, it would be useful to see exactly how you are compiling them, so that we can for example see what level of compiler optimizations you are applying.

Comment: remove the "volatile" qualifier form `a` and `b` arrays. Its presence cripples pretty much all possible optimizations.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel wow I totally missed that.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I just use `go run` when I run the go programs and `make ` when i compile the C program

Comment: @mama: And does your makefile (which is used when you call `make`) apply compiler optimizations? With the compilers gcc and clang, you should generally be using the `-O3` command-line option to apply full optimizations.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I don't use a make file, I juse use the make command on the c file. I think they don't use -O3 optimizations, but I will definitely check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concurrency speeds up execution time.

Go program:

Elapsed time (us) = 130768

Go program with concurrency:

Elapsed time (us) = 66947

For each goroutine to have its own rand.Rand instance, use rand.New(src Source).

---

Run a Go version of the C program.

`x.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

const size = 10000000

var (
    a = [size]float32{}
    b = [size]float32{}
)

func main() {
    start := time.Now()

    r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        a[i] = r.Float32()
        b[i] = r.Float32()
    }

    sum := 0.0
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        sum += float64(a[i]) * float64(b[i])
    }

    since := time.Since(start).Microseconds()
    fmt.Printf("Elapsed time (us) = %d\n", since)
}
```

.

```
$ go build x.go && ./x
Elapsed time (us) = 130768
$
```

---

Run a concurrent Go version of the C program.

`y.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

const size = 10000000

var (
    a = [size]float32{}
    b = [size]float32{}
)

func main() {
    start := time.Now()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))
        for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
            a[i] = r.Float32()
        }
    }()
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))
        for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
            b[i] = r.Float32()
        }
    }()
    wg.Wait()

    sum := 0.0
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        sum += float64(a[i]) * float64(b[i])
    }

    since := time.Since(start).Microseconds()
    fmt.Printf("Elapsed time (us) = %d\n", since)
}
```

.

```
$ go build y.go && ./y
Elapsed time (us) = 66947
$
```